# Access COM objects on another box from .NET (without deprecated DCOM, remoting)

Tags: .net, wcf, com, dcom, .net-remoting

I have to integrate my .NET server app with a vendor's product. The vendor's product will be on its own server and has a supported & documented API, but alas, only as COM objects. Since DCOM and .NET remoting are both deprecated, is there a supported (i.e. not at risk of being removed in .NET 5) way to perform this integration without having to create & install a web service on the vendor box & web client on my box to proxy these requests across the network to COM?

Note that I'm very comfortable writing & consuming web services (REST when I can, SOAP when I have to). I'd just like to keep the topography of this app simple, avoid dual deploys, etc. For the same reason, I've avoided WCF since it seems like a lot of overhead, but if WCF supports exposing the underlying COM interface over the network, I'd happily use it. Otherwise, I guess I'm designing, writing, deploying, & consuming this new web service. Please show me I don't have to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using [WCF features for integration with COM+ applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734723.aspx)

Comment: Researching both these options now (WCF for COM+, COM+ remoting) and will report back (and pick a winner) soon. Thanks!

Comment: Going with this answer as it seems to be the least hackish. However, I ended up deciding to bite the bullet and write a traditional web service (which may or may not use WCF). Vendor support & our ability to trust the finished product would be impossible any other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a COM+ application and then access it from the remote machine.

DCOM might be deprecated but COM+ is not, and allows for remote calls.  You'd need COM interop on the client side, as well as custom activation (you won't be able to just call `new` to create the instance, as you have to indicate the remote machine) but it's definitely doable.

Comment: Researching both these options now (WCF for COM+, COM+ remoting) and will report back (and pick a winner) soon. Thanks!